# VBA - Change column in R1C1 Formula from offset of 1 to offset of 2

Tags: vba, excel

It's difficult to explain what I'm looking for, but I'll try...

I am creating a report that uses formulas from a template sheet for a report on another sheet using R1C1 formulas. For example, Column 2 Row 1 equals Column 1 Row 1 times 2. The formula on the template page is "=RC[-1]*2". The problem is that on the page where the actual report will be, there is a blank column between each column of figures. Therefore, when I copy the formula from the template sheet the R1C1 column offset needs to be doubled, or "=RC[-2]*2".

How can I process the string to double the column offset. I know I can break up the string and segregate the number portion, but I assume there's a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll have to do it like this:

```
If InStr(a, "C[") Then
    a = Left(a, InStr(a, "C[") + 1) & (Mid(a, InStr(a, "C[") + 2, Len(a) - InStr(a, "C[") - 2) * 2) & "]"
ElseIf IsNumeric(Right(a, 1)) Then
    a = Left(a, InStr(a, "C")) & (Right(a, Len(a) - InStr(a, "C")) * 2)
End If
```